# Send rtp packet between two rtpproxy server

Tags: sockets, asterisk, rtp, kamailio, opensips

Is it possible to send media rtp packets from one rtpproxy server to another rtpproxy server?

In my scenario , i am registering voip account via opensips proxy server. We have rtpproxy and opensips server hosted on same place. opensips changes c= and m= lines of SDP accordingly but when packet goes to voip switch , its rtpproxy server also changes SDP. So Peer1 is sending packets to hout hosted rtpproxy server and peer2 sending rtp packets to voip switch's rtpproxy server.

SIP packets : Peer <--> opensips <--> asterisk

RTP packets peer1 <--> rtpproxy1      =X=      rtpproxy2 <-->peer2

here no connection between rtpproxy1 and rtpproxy 2 so no media transfer between peer1 and peer2. Please help to solve this problem.

my opensips.cfg file is as below.

```
#
# $Id: opensips.cfg 9742 2013-02-05 10:24:48Z vladut-paiu $
#
# OpenSIPS residential configuration script
#     by OpenSIPS Solutions <team@opensips-solutions.com>
#
# This script was generated via "make menuconfig", from
#   the "Residential" scenario.
# You can enable / disable more features / functionalities by
#   re-generating the scenario with different options.#
#
# Please refer to the Core CookBook at:
#      http://www.opensips.org/Resources/DocsCookbooks
# for a explanation of possible statements, functions and parameters.
#


####### Global Parameters #########

debug=4
log_stderror=no
log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0

fork=yes
children=4

sip_warning=yes


mhomed=1
/* uncomment the following lines to enable debugging */
#debug=6
#fork=no
#log_stderror=yes

/* uncomment the next line to enable the auto temporary blacklisting of 
   not available destinations (default disabled) */
#disable_dns_blacklist=no

/* uncomment the next line to enable IPv6 lookup after IPv4 dns 
   lookup failures (default disabled) */
#dns_try_ipv6=yes

/* comment the next line to enable the auto discovery of local aliases
   based on revers DNS on IPs */
auto_aliases=yes


#listen=udp:127.0.0.1:5060   # CUSTOMIZE ME

listen=udp:192.168.1.28:5080

disable_tcp=yes
listen=tcp:192.168.1.28:5080

disable_tls = yes
listen = tls:192.168.1.28:5081
tls_verify_server = 1
tls_verify_client = 1
tls_require_client_certificate = 0
tls_method = TLSv1
tls_certificate = "/usr/local/etc/opensips/tls/server/server-cert.pem"
tls_private_key = "/usr/local/etc/opensips/tls/server/server-privkey.pem"
tls_ca_list = "/usr/local/etc/opensips/tls/server/server-calist.pem"


####### Modules Section ########


#set module path
mpath="/usr/local/lib64/opensips/modules/"

#### Auth db module


loadmodule "db_mysql.so"



loadmodule "auth_db.so"

loadmodule "auth.so"

modparam("auth_db", "db_url", "mysql://root:admin@localhost/opensips")
modparam("auth_db", "calculate_ha1", yes)
modparam("auth_db", "password_column", "password")
modparam("auth_db", "use_domain", 1)

modparam("auth", "nonce_expire", 300) 
modparam("auth", "rpid_suffix", ";party=calling;id-type=subscriber;screen=yes") 
modparam("auth", "rpid_avp", "$avp(rpid)") 

# !! Nathelper 
loadmodule "nathelper.so" 
#loadmodule "nat_traversal.so" 
loadmodule "rtpproxy.so" 
loadmodule "textops.so"
# ----------------- setting module-specific parameters --------------- 

modparam("rtpproxy", "rtpproxy_sock", "udp:192.168.1.28:7890") 

# !! Nathelper 

modparam("nathelper","sipping_bflag",7) 
modparam("nathelper", "ping_nated_only", 1)   # Ping only clients behind NAT 
modparam("nathelper", "force_socket", "udp:192.168.1.28:7890")
modparam("nathelper", "nortpproxy_str", "a=sdpmangled:yes\r\n")
#### SIGNALING module
loadmodule "signaling.so"

#### StateLess module
loadmodule "sl.so"

#### Transaction Module
loadmodule "tm.so"
modparam("tm", "fr_timer", 5)
modparam("tm", "fr_inv_timer", 30)
modparam("tm", "restart_fr_on_each_reply", 0)
modparam("tm", "onreply_avp_mode", 1)

#### Record Route Module
loadmodule "rr.so"
/* do not append from tag to the RR (no need for this script) */
modparam("rr", "append_fromtag", 0)

#### MAX ForWarD module
loadmodule "maxfwd.so"

#### SIP MSG OPerationS module
loadmodule "sipmsgops.so"

#### FIFO Management Interface
loadmodule "mi_fifo.so"
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_name", "/tmp/opensips_fifo")
modparam("mi_fifo", "fifo_mode", 0666)

#### URI module
loadmodule "uri.so"
modparam("uri", "use_uri_table", 0)
modparam("uri", "use_domain", 0)   
modparam("uri", "db_url", "mysql://root:admin@localhost/opensips") 
#### USeR LOCation module
loadmodule "usrloc.so"
modparam("usrloc","nat_bflag",6) 
modparam("usrloc", "db_mode",   0)

#### REGISTRAR module
loadmodule "registrar.so"
modparam("registrar", "tcp_persistent_flag", "TCP_PERSISTENT")

modparam("registrar", "default_expires", 3600) 
modparam("registrar", "min_expires", 60) 
modparam("registrar", "max_expires", 0) 
modparam("registrar", "default_q", 0) 
modparam("registrar", "case_sensitive", 0) 
modparam("registrar", "received_param", "received") 
modparam("registrar", "max_contacts", 0) 
modparam("registrar", "retry_after", 0) 
modparam("registrar", "received_avp", "$avp(i:801)") 

/* uncomment the next line not to allow more than 10 contacts per AOR */
#modparam("registrar", "max_contacts", 10)
modparam("registrar","received_avp", "$avp(42)")
modparam("nathelper","received_avp", "$avp(42)")

#### ACCounting module
loadmodule "acc.so"
/* what special events should be accounted ? */
modparam("acc", "early_media", 0)
modparam("acc", "report_cancels", 0)
/* by default we do not adjust the direct of the sequential requests.
   if you enable this parameter, be sure the enable "append_fromtag"
   in "rr" module */
modparam("acc", "detect_direction", 0)
modparam("acc", "failed_transaction_flag", "ACC_FAILED")
/* account triggers (flags) */
modparam("acc", "log_flag", "ACC_DO")
modparam("acc", "log_missed_flag", "ACC_MISSED")

loadmodule "dialog.so"
#loadmodule "load_balancer.so"
loadmodule "domain.so"

modparam("domain", "db_url","mysql://root:admin@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME
modparam("domain", "db_mode", 1)   # Use caching
modparam("auth_db|usrloc|uri", "use_domain", 1)

loadmodule "drouting.so"

modparam("drouting", "db_url","mysql://root:admin@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME

loadmodule "event_route.so"
#loadmodule "mediaproxy.so"
loadmodule "alias_db.so" 

modparam("alias_db", "db_url","mysql://root:admin@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME

loadmodule "dialplan.so" 

modparam("dialplan", "db_url","mysql://root:admin@localhost/opensips") # CUSTOMIZE ME

#loadmodule "presence_xcapdiff.so"
#loadmodule "permissions.so"
####### Routing Logic ########

# main routing logic
# main request routing logic


route 
{

    #xlog("L_INFO","CVAPP: route($rm/$du/$fu/$tu)"); 

    #script_trace( 1, "$rm from $si, ruri=$ru", "me");

    #xlog("L_INFO", "route[0] New request - M=$rm RURI=$ru F=$fu T=$tu IP=$si ID=$ci\n"); 
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    # Sanity Check Section
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    if (!mf_process_maxfwd_header("10"))
    {   
        xlog("mf_process_maxfwd_header....... \n");
        sl_send_reply("483", "Too Many Hops");
        exit;
    };
    if (msg:len > 4096) 
    {
        xlog(" method msg:len > 2048 \n");
        sl_send_reply("513", "Message Overflow");   
        exit;
    };

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    # Record Route Section
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    if (method!="REGISTER") 
    {
        record_route();
    }
    else
    {
        if(nat_uac_test("19")) 
                { 
                        record_route(";nat=yes"); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                        record_route(); 
                } 
    }
    if (method=="BYE" || method=="CANCEL") 
    {
        unforce_rtp_proxy();
    }

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    # Loose Route Section nat_uac_test("3")
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    if (loose_route()) 
    {
        xlog(" method loose_route() \n");
        if ((method=="INVITE" || method=="REFER") && !has_totag()) 
        {
            sl_send_reply("403", "Forbidden");
            exit;
        };
        if (method=="INVITE") 
        {
            fix_nated_sdp("1");
            if (nat_uac_test("19")) 
            {
                xlog(" method fix_nated_contact() \n");
                #setflag(6);
                setbflag(6);
                setbflag(7);
                setbflag(8);
                force_rport();
                fix_nated_contact("2");
            };

               rtpproxy_answer();
        };

        route(1);
        exit;
    };


            #xlog("L_INFO","CVAPP:  has_totag initial request"); 

            /* if(loose_route()) 
                { 
                        if(!has_totag()) 
                        { 
                                xlog("L_INFO", "route[0] Initial loose-routing rejected - M=$rm RURI=$ru F=$fu T=$tu IP=$si ID=$ci\n"); 
                                sl_send_reply("403", "Initial Loose-Routing Rejected"); 
                                exit; 
                        } 
                        if(nat_uac_test("19") || search("^Route:.*;nat=yes")) 
                        { 
                                xlog("L_INFO", "route[0] Initial loose-routing 19 - M=$rm RURI=$ru F=$fu T=$tu IP=$si ID=$ci\n"); 
                                fix_nated_contact(); 
                                setbflag(6); 
                        } 
                        xlog("loose_route route5....... \n");
                        route(5); 
                } */

                /* else { 
                                 xlog("L_INFO","CVAPP:   loose_route was false"); 
                                 if ( is_method("ACK") ) { 
                                         xlog("L_INFO","CVAPP:   is ACK"); 
                                         if ( t_check_trans() ) { 
                                                 xlog("L_INFO","CVAPP:   found matching transaction"); 
                                                 # non loose-route, but stateful ACK; must be an ACK after 
                                                 # a 487 or e.g. 404 from upstream server 
                                                 t_relay(); 
                                                 exit; 
                                         } else { 
                                                 xlog("L_INFO","CVAPP:   no matching transaction"); 
                                                 # ACK without matching   transaction -> 
                                                 # ignore and discard 
                                                 exit; 
                                         } 
                                 } 
                                 xlog("L_INFO","CVAPP:   sending 404 Not here"); 
                                 sl_send_reply("404","Not here"); 
                         }  
                */

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    # Call Type Processing Section
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    if (uri!=myself) 
    {
        #xlog("L_INFO", "uri!=myself1...........\n"); 
        route(4);
        route(1);
        exit;
    };

    if (method=="ACK") 
    {
        xlog(" method==ACK \n");
        route(1);
        exit;
    } 
    if (method=="CANCEL") 
    {
        xlog(" method==CANCEL \n");
        route(1);
        exit;
    } 
    else if (method=="INVITE") 
    {
        xlog(" method==INVITE \n");
        route(3);
        exit;
    } 
    else if (method=="REGISTER") 
    {
        xlog(" method==REGISTER \n");
        route(2);
        exit;
    };
    lookup("aliases");
    if (uri!=myself) 
    {
        xlog(" uri!=myself2... \n");
        route(4);
        route(1);
        exit;
    };
    if (!lookup("location")) 
    {
        xlog(" !lookup(location) \n");
        sl_send_reply("404", "User Not Found");
        exit;
    };

    route(1);
}


route[1] 
{
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    # Default Message Handler
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------



         # if client or server know to be behind a NAT, enable relay
        if (isflagset(6) || isflagset(7)) {

                xlog("route[1]  Default Message Handler \n");

                force_rport();
                fix_nated_contact();
                rtpproxy_answer();
        };

    t_on_reply("1");

    if (subst_uri('/(sip:.*);nat=yes/\1/')){
        xlog("subst_uri ..............\n");
        setbflag(6);
    };


    if (!t_relay()) 
    {
        if (method=="INVITE" && isbflagset(6)) 
        {
            unforce_rtp_proxy();
        };
        sl_reply_error();
    };
}

route[2] 
{
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    # REGISTER Message Handler
    # ----------------------------------------------------------------

    xlog("route[2]  REGISTER Message Handler \n");

    if (!search("^Contact:[ ]*\*") && nat_uac_test("19")) 
    {   

        xlog(" !search()...... \n");
        #setflag(6);
        setbflag(6);
        setbflag(8);
        #fix_nated_register();
        fix_nated_contact();
        force_rport();
    };

    sl_send_reply("100", "Trying");

    if (!save("location")) 
    {
        sl_reply_error();
    };
}

route[3] 
{
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    # INVITE Message Handler
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    #if (nat_uac_test("19")) 
    #{
    #   setflag(6);
    #}
    xlog("route[3]  INVITE Message Handler \n");
    #linha incluida por mim para fazer com que todo INVITE utilize o rtpproxy
        #setflag(6);
    setbflag(6);
    setbflag(8);

    lookup("aliases");

    if (uri!=myself) 
    {
        route(4);
        route(1);
        exit;
    };

    if (!lookup("location")) 
    {
        sl_send_reply("404", "User Not Found");
        exit;
    };
    route(4);
    route(1);
}

route[4]
{
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    # NAT Traversal Section
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    if (isbflagset(6)) 
    {
        force_rport();
        fix_nated_contact();
        rtpproxy_answer(); 
    }
}

route[5] 
{ 
        if(isbflagset(6)) 
        { 

            xlog("L_INFO", "route[5] ..............."); 

                if(!isflagset(22) && !search("^Content-Length:[ ]*0")) 
                { 

                        setflag(22); 
#    force_rtp_proxy(); 
#    fix_nated_sdp("9");


                    if(has_body("application/sdp"))
                    {
                                xlog("L_INFO", "has_body rtpproxy_answer IP..............."); 
                                #rtpproxy_offer(); 
                                fix_nated_sdp("10","192.168.1.28");
                                rtpproxy_answer("r","192.168.1.28");
                    }
                } 

#    if (rtpproxy_offer()) 
#    { 
#    t_on_reply("2"); 
#    } 
                t_on_reply("2"); 

        } 
        else 
        { 
                t_on_reply("1"); 
        } 
        if(!isflagset(21)) 
        { 
                t_on_failure("1"); 
        } 
        if(isflagset(29)) 
        { 
                append_branch(); 
        } 
       /* if(is_present_hf("Proxy-Authorization")) 
        { 
                consume_credentials(); 
        } 
        */
        xlog("L_INFO", "route[3] Request leaving server, D-URI='$du' - M=$rm RURI=$ru F=$fu T=$tu IP=$si ID=$ci\n"); 
        # no 100 (we already sent it) and no DNS blacklisting 
#   if(!t_relay("0x05")) 
        if(!t_relay()) 
        { 
                sl_reply_error(); 
                if(is_method("INVITE") && isbflagset(6)) 
                { 
                        xlog("L_INFO", "route[3] unforce rtp proxy\n"); 
                        unforce_rtp_proxy(); 
                } 
        } 
        exit; 

} 

onreply_route[1] 
{

    #rtpproxy_answer(); 
    #force_rport();
    #fix_nated_contact();
    #rtpproxy_answer(); 
    #rtpproxy_offer("i");
    #rtpproxy_answer("cowf","192.168.1.28");

    if (is_method("INVITE") || is_method("ACK") )
    {
        if(has_body("application/sdp"))
        {
                $var(mline) = $(rb{sdp.line,m});
            xlog("The first m line in the SDP body is $var(mline)\n");
            force_rport();
            #fix_nated_contact();
            fix_nated_sdp("3");
            rtpproxy_offer("i");
        }

    }   
    #rtpproxy_answer("cowf","192.168.1.28");


    if (isbflagset(6) && status=~"2[0-9][0-9]") 
    {

        if (!search("^Content-Length:[ ]*0")) 
        {
             xlog("onreply_route[1]  if1 \n");
             rtpproxy_answer(); 
        };
    };
    if (nat_uac_test("1")) 
    {
            xlog("onreply_route[1]  if2 \n");
        fix_nated_contact();
    };
}

onreply_route[2] 
{ 
        xlog("L_INFO", "onreply_route[2] NAT-Reply - S=$rs D=$rr F=$fu T=$tu IP=$si ID=$ci\n"); 
        if(nat_uac_test("1")) 
        { 
                fix_nated_contact(); 
        } 
        if(isbflagset(6) && status=~"2[0-9][0-9]") 
        { 
                if(!search("^Content-Length:[ ]*0")) 
                { 
                        #force_rtp_proxy(); 
                        xlog("L_INFO", "onreply_route[2] - calling rtpproxy_answer()\n");   
                        #fix_nated_sdp("3"); 
                        rtpproxy_answer(); 
                } 
        } 

        exit; 
} 

failure_route[1]{

    xlog("failure_route[1]  if2 \n");

}
```

Comment: If you're satisfied by my answer, please accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change r`tpproxy_offer(i)` to `rtpproxy_offer("corw")` in your `onreply_route[2]` function.

```
rtpproxy_offer("corw");
```

Answer (score 1):

When the first SIP proxy receives the initial `INVITE`, it will allocate ports on the first `rtpproxy` and modify the SDP body so that traffic destinated to the UAC is sent to this `rtpproxy`. When the `INVITE` reaches the second SIP proxy (or B2BUA if it is Asterisk), it will allocate ports on the second `rtpproxy` and modify the SDP body so that traffic destinated to the UAC is sent to this `rtpproxy`. The opposite will also happen when replies with SDP body are received by the proxies.

Therefore, the traffic will flow as follows:

```
UAC <-> rtpproxy1 <-> rtpproxy2 <-> UAS
```

And, there is no special configuration for the two `rtpproxy` to send each other traffic. Each `rtpproxy` is simply seen by the other as the UA (UAS or UAC).